# Guidance for having a WCF Singleton

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a 3rd party object that I want to wrap in my WCF service. It is a singleton object and I want it to initalize when the WCF initalizes and shutdown when the WCF shuts down.

My initial thoughts are to make this a static, but I know there are strange things when the app pool gets reset and the static variables get wiped out.

What is the best practice way that people would typically handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of any strangeness with static variables and an AppPool reset.  Since we are dealing with a static object, you are guaranteed thread safe initialization before a request is serviced.

I think the most important question(s) here is: "Will your service handle multiple simultaneous requests?".  In other words, what is the [ConcurrencyMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting of your service?  The default value is Single, which means your service will only service one request at a time.  In this case, we don't have to worry about the thread safety of the singleton object.

If ConcurrencyMode == Multiple then your singleton object can be accessed by multiple simultaneous requests.  In this scenario you must be sure your singleton object is [thread safe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)

The code below has served me well in a high volume production system.  Note that ConcurrencyMode.Multiple has been specified, as the SearchManager class is thread safe. I'm certain this setup this can be improved upon.

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class SearchService : ISearchService
{

    // My Singleton
    private static SearchManager engine = SearchManager.GetEngine();

    // all subsequent services make use of the engine instance
}
```

This code has also specified InstanceContextMode.PerCall, meaning each request is serviced with a new instance of the serivce